# How to generate "css-vars.js" in Sencha ExtJS 6.2

Tags: extjs, themes, sencha-fashion

I generated a new Sencha ExtJS 6.2.1 project using the command:

```
sencha -sdk "c:\Program Files\ext-6.2.1" generate app MyTest1 c:\MyTest1
```

Then, I generated a new theme:

```
sencha generate theme theme-foo
```

I modified the `app.json` so that it uses my new theme.

The question is: how to generate the file `css-vars.js`, that contains the `Fashion` javascript class? I need this class to be able to change the values of CSS variables at run-time. I tried all the following Sencha CMD commands, without success:

```
sencha app build modern development
sencha app build modern production
sencha app watch modern
sencha app build
sencha app build development
sencha app build production
```

Comment: The new theme has to derive from the Material Theme, which is, as of now, the only theme that supports the new Fashion javascript class.

Comment: @Alexander Will you please add your comment as an answer? I derived my theme from theme-material and the class is generated! How could you know? I couldn't find this information anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Fashion javascript classes (which support modification of the CSS variables) were introduced with ExtJS 6.2.1](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/guides/whats_new/whats_new.html#whats_new-_-whats_new_-_material_theme); no legacy themes that already existed in ExtJS 6.2.0 were updated to support it. From my experience since ExtJS 4.x, I suspect that the legacy themes won't ever be updated to make use of it; instead, I expect Sencha to bring a new theme for classic toolkit in one of the next versions. Some (most? all?) of the legacy themes of the modern toolkit are even deprecated now.

So, the only themes that can support Fashion javascript at all are `theme-material` and `theme-ios` introduced in ExtJS 6.2.1. I am not sure whether `theme-ios` does, but the samples show that `theme-material` is definitely using these classes.

If you derive your theme from one of the themes which already uses this feature, you will be good to go. If you really want to derive from a different theme, you would have to ask specialized Sencha personnel how to bootstrap a completely new theme which uses this feature; I don't know of any publicly available resources that break down these things into their nuts and bolts.

So, if you want to use this feature for apps based on the classic toolkit, you definitely have to ask for assistance from Sencha right now.